# What is taking the storage of my Huawei phone?

Tags: storage, huawei

Update: The suggested duplicate  question does not indicate how to solve it, nor do I think it explains the situation unless there is a unusual amount in the hidden folders

---

I recently did a factory reset reset on my Huawei P8 lite 2017, and as soon as I installed a few apps if started to complain about memory.

I looked at it from every angle I could think of and it just doesn't seem to make sense. Here is a screenshot of the memory usage:

[image]

My question:

## Where did the remaining memory go, can I free it up?

Note that I am not allowed to root the phone

Comment: @irfan The accepted answer to that question does not indicate how to solve it, nor do I think it explains the situation unless there is a unusual amount in the hidden folders

Comment: Please consider reading my answer too. That explains in very detail **Where did the remaining storage go?**. Then you'll be able to decide easily **Can I free it up?**

Comment: Have added that I cannot root the phone, does this mean there is basically nothing I can do? Fwiw: I suspect OS update files are responsible for about half of the gap, and cannot believe a phone of 2017 is completely unusable today.

Comment: Right. I know mostly users can't and won't root their phones but the fact is you can't do a 100% analysis of space usage without root access. As a solution what you can do is factory reset and at maximum flashing factory firmware through some bootloader mode.

Comment: The storage summary is not very helpful without knowing the partitions. Use [Disk Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) to get the info on your partitions, especially how large the user data partition is.